# trouble replacing keys in a document with spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm writing a script that will take data from a spreadsheet and replace text keys on a document, adding one duplicated page to the document for each row of data on the spreadsheet.

the script was working properly when i created some test arrays with dummy data but it's not working when i try to pull the data from the spreadsheet.

```
function requestGen3() {
  var templateDocID = ScriptProperties.getProperty("backRxRequestDocID");
  // go back to variable below after testing
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheet = sheets[3];
  var activeSheetName = sheet.getName();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var user = Session.getUser().getEmail();


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
//    the problem seems to be somewhere between here....
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  // For every row of employee data, generate an employee object.
  var ptObjects = getRowsData(sheet, range);

  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
  var docID = DocsList.getFileById(templateDocID).makeCopy().getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
  var body = doc.getActiveSection();
  var pars = doc.getParagraphs();
  for( var i in pars ) //loop to keep a copy of the original paragraphs
    pars[i] = pars[i].copy();

  // Create an array for every row object
  for (var i = 0; i < ptObjects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = ptObjects[i];

    for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i) {
      // Replace place holder keys,  
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_NAME%', rowData.physName[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_ADDR1%', rowData.physAddr1[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_ADDR2%', rowData.physAddr2[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_CITY%', rowData.physCity[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_STATE%', rowData.physState[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_ZIP%', rowData.physZip[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PHYS_PHONE%', rowData.physPhone[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PT_NAME%', rowData.firstName[i]);
      body.replaceText('%PT_DOB%', rowData.ptDOB[i]);
      if( i != physName.length-1 ) { //has next?
        doc.appendPageBreak();
        for( var j in pars )
          doc.appendParagraph(pars[j].copy());
      }
    }
  }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//     ...... and here
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  // Save and close the document
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

the other functions referenced are from the "reading data from a spreadsheet" tutorial. when i debug the script it seems like the **ptObjects** and **rowData** variables contain the right information but it is not replacing the keys (which are formatted %KEY_NAME%) in the document properly. i'm fairly new to this so there may be some obvious mistakes.

any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could a simple problem assuming that the getRowsData function is the one described in the [Reading Spreadsheet Data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/reading_spreadsheet_data) tutorial from the Apps Script Articles site.

That being the case, `rowData.physName[i]` should simply be `rowData.physName`.

Comment: that makes perfect sense now. unfortunately i'll have to wait to fully test it since i am getting an "exceeded maximum instruction count error" now. should i ask a separate question about that or add it here - sorry i'm new, still getting my feet wet.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this too, but I think you should ask a new question for that one, I don't think I've experienced that one! Don't forget to tick this as the right answer if it does solve your problem though.